# What should be the size of a lifting body aircraft that can carry 5 passengers (385kg/850lbs)?

Tags: lift, weight-and-balance, weight, lifting-body

So I just want to know the size of an aircraft with a lifting body that would fly at low altitudes (around 40 meters/100 feet), and at low speeds (maximum 200 km/h 124 mph). But I don't know if these numbers are even useful to the question.

I tried to search for more aircraft like that, but most of them just fit a single person (the pilot).

I did find some illustrations from reentry lifting body aircraft (like the [Martin X-23 Prime](https://cdn-cavok.nuneshost.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Martin-Marietta.jpg)), but I can't tell if they are 1:1 or simply an illustration.

I did find the [Wainfan Facetmobile FMX-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wainfan_Facetmobile) quite simple and interesting, I don't know how fast and how high this aircraft can fly, but I think it could be a simple way of scaling things up.

I found [this video](https://youtu.be/jO0CUODtWCM) of the FMX-4 showing its frame and engine (and other stuff), I don't know if it will be useful, but...

[image: The FMX-4 Facetmobile in flight]

Comment: Lifting bodies are good for high speed descents like reentry.  I’m no engineer, but even without math I can tell you that you will have difficulty flying 5 adults at 124 mph in a craft shaped like that.  You will need some more wingspan.

Comment: "This isn't flying. It's falling with style."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "lifting body" [as it is defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_body) does not match with slower than 200km/h flight speed, since those are very low aspect ratio, thick & highly loaded flying wing meant to also fly hypersonic.

The Facetmobile you mentioned has a far lower wing loading, which is a good approach. Further searching for images of this particular aircraft lead to this example too :

[image]

(http://www.hitechweb.genezis.eu/liftingbodies2.htm)

It may be possible to increase the Facetmobile wingspan and fit passengers side by side.

[image]

Another approach could be to scale up well known lifting bodies such as [X-24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Marietta_X-24#/media/File:Martin_X-24A_3-view.svg) or [HL-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_HL-10#/media/File:NASA_HL-10_diagram.png), build them as a light structure covered with fabric, and fill those with a lifting gas, since lifting bodies tend to maximize their volume to surface ratio.

*

Comment: Wow! You even made a 3d model to illustrate your answer! This is really cool!

Comment: accepting an answer too fast may discourage other to answer, you can move or remove a checkmark anytime, thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

Going slow the problem is lift.  Going fast the problem is drag.  What you have there in the picture is essentially a scaled-up paper airplane design, which works surprisingly well provided there is enough thrust available.

Birds fold their wings back for higher speed flight.  Turboprop carriers also feature undersized *straight* wings.

What is needed for craft such as these **is the ability to take off and land at higher airspeeds**.  You won't be landing one of these in the bush or at a small local airport.

Other than that, scaling should be easy.  One might plan for a bit more than 375 kg, considering 5 people, the pilot, and fuel.

Comment: `which works surprisingly well provided there is enough thrust available.` I think it is safe to say that given enough thrust, anything works surprisingly well. ;-)

Comment: @DeltaLima - Yes! Just look at the F4 Phantom. :-)  (My absolute favorite airplane as a kid)

Answer (score 2):

NASA extensively studied lifting bodies back in the 60s. Its repository is therefore full with the [relevant documents](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=Lifting%20body).

I think [this](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19670003792), [this](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19980169231) and [this](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19720004251) could be useful for your project, but there are really many more.

Anyway I agree with the answer of @qqjkztd: lifting bodies were designed to study the re-entry phase of the future space shuttle and their main purpose was to glide (not fly) at extreme Mach numbers.

Maybe the kind of aircraft you are looking for is a *flying wing*?